# Finding sentences with specific cosine similarity ratio

Tags: linear-algebra

Let me preface by saying this is a homework question, I am not looking for the answer - just guidance on how to solve the question.

## Background

This is based on text vectorization, which is listed here: https://towardsdatascience.com/text-vectorization-term-frequency-inverse-document-frequency-tfidf-5a3f9604da6d

Essentially, given a set of "documents" (in their simplest form, just strings of words), we can determine their similarity to other words following the above process. All of the documents that we are comparing against, is called a "corpus".

## Example

```
corpus = [
    "the dog ran", # each entry is a 'document'
    "the dog saw",
    "my cat saw"
]
```

Given the above, we can formula the Term-Frequency (TF) as
$$ TF(w,d) = \frac{occurrences\ of\ w\ in\ document\ d}{total\ number\ of\ words\ in\ document\ d} $$

This generates the following matrix:

[image: TF scores]

We can then calculate the Inverse Document Frequency (IDF) as follows:

$$ IDF(w,D) = \ln{(\frac{Total\ number\ of\ documents\ (N)\ in\ corpus\ D}{number\ of\ documents\ containing\ w})} $$

This generates the following values:
[image]

We can then calculate the TFIDF as
$$ TFIDF(w,d,D) =  TF(w,d) * IDF(w,D) $$

This generates the following matrix (see TFIDF columns):

[image]

Following this, we can take the vector of each document (the columns TFIDF A, TFIDF B, TFIDF C) to see the "cosine similarity" of these documents, which is calculated as:

$$ cos\theta = \frac{\overrightarrow{a}\cdot\overrightarrow{b}}{\lVert \overrightarrow{a}\rVert\lVert \overrightarrow{b}\rVert} $$

to get

```
cos similarity of A and B: 0.3778002039938993
cos similarity of B and C: 0.1457894663281049
ratio = 2.591409472229256
```

## The Question

I am trying to take generate a set of sentences such that $a$ and $b$ will have a cosine similarity of the TF-IDF vector representations exactly $n$ times larger than $b$ and $c$

Using the definition of the cosine similarity it would make sense we simply want

$$ \frac{\overrightarrow{a}\cdot\overrightarrow{b}}{\lVert \overrightarrow{a}\rVert\lVert \overrightarrow{b}\rVert} = n*\frac{\overrightarrow{b}\cdot\overrightarrow{c}}{\lVert \overrightarrow{b}\rVert\lVert \overrightarrow{c}\rVert} $$

This is clearly true for an infinite number of vectors (and I assume it will hold for an infinite number of sentences as well)

Since $\overrightarrow{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}$ are generated based on the $term frequency * inverse document frequency$ for each word in the corpus, I am having a hard time seeing how I can formulate the equation that I need to solve to generate the matrix that will make the corpus (I assume there is some system of linear equations I need to be solving). Furthermore, the fact that $length(\overrightarrow{a})$ doesn't need to be the same as $length(\overrightarrow{b})$ or $length(\overrightarrow{c})$ kind of throws me off, otherwise I might be able to find a minimum size vector that is required to hold true and then maybe expand the formulas based on this assumption.

Thanks for any guidance you can offer.

Comment: The reason you haven't received any replies is because no one who has read this has understood what you are talking about - at least no one with the wherewithal to answer. You are clearly working in some specialty application, and are tossing around its jargon as if everyone should understand it, when in fact very few people in this forum will have had any exposure to it at all. "Corpus", "sentences", "similarity", "TF-IDF representation vector", "length of a vector" are all terms you need to explain. For example, in math jargon, the length of a vector is just another name for its norm.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSinclair - sorry I didn't realize this - I'll edit the question.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I have added background information and an example, is this enough information or should add more? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Even if you removed stop words and made everything lower case, constructing sentences would likely require brute-force guessing. An algorithmic approach won't give you semantically correct sentences since TFIDF and cosine similarity ignore language semantics, context and synonyms.  I'm curious to know the "meaning" behind finding three phrases, A, B and C, such that A's similarity to B is n times B's similarity to C.  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @belwood It didn't need to be semantically correct. I did in fact end up brute forcing it. It was a poorly designed assignment question that the prof himself couldn't answer exactly how to do it. Brute force worked.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I feel better that I'm not missing something.  I tried it myself using 50k music review summaries from amazon.  I searched for that relationship among the pairwise cos similarity (rounded to 6 dec) of the phrases.  As expected, the resulting triplets of phrases had nothing meaningful in common.